# check if the ok button of a dialog fragment is clicked - android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a dialog fragment as shown that displays an okay buttom and a cancel button. How can I check if the ok button of the dialog fragment is clicked. Below is a code snippet

```
DialogFragment dialog = TextEditDialogFragment.newInstance(FragmentActivity.this,
                    R.id.profile_setting_linear_layout_name, name, R.string.firstname, R.string.ok, R.string.cancel);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "First Name");
if(ok button is clicked){
//do something else
}
```

assistance much appreciated

Comment: user interface pattern (Listener pattern)..

Comment: If you want to do something after the click then attach a listener.

Comment: see my answer below, using listener

Answer (score 0):

try this 
**at top of your activity so you can access any where in your activity like this**

```
//declare boolean
public boolean clicked=false;
```

**button  perform click event in your dialog button onclick listener like this**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    //button is clicked change boolean value
    clicked=true;
}
});
```

now perform action of  button clicked or not clicked  as per your reqiement
        if(clicked)
       {
          // perform your action here
       }
       else
       {
         // other actions
       }

Comment: declare your boolean variable at top. than set on button click listener to your dialog fragment and check if candition as per your requiement

Comment: cannot resolve symbol, set onclick listener >>>>>
button.setOnClickListener

Comment: add setonclicklistner to you dialog fragment buttton my friend

Comment: ill adwisw you to add button click listner to your dialog fragment button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148886/discussion-between-parker-and-nilesh-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
            import android.app.Dialog;
            import android.content.DialogInterface;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

            public class AlertDFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private EventListenr el;
    public void setListenre(EventListenr el){
    this.el=el;}

                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            // Set Dialog Icon
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.androidhappy)
                            // Set Dialog Title
                            .setTitle("Alert DialogFragment")
                            // Set Dialog Message
                            .setMessage("Alert DialogFragment Tutorial")

                            // Positive button
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // Do something else
                             el.okClick();
                                }
                            })

                            // Negative Button
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // Do something else
                                }
                            }).create();
                }
            }

    interface EventListener{
    void okClick();
    }
```

on Activity etc.

```
alertDialog.setLisnter(this);
```

implement activity or fragment by EventListenr

Comment: I am afraid I may do much work on my code to use this solution

Comment: you can update your TextEditDialogFragment. you just need to set a listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Above in your class:

```
private boolean clicked;
```

When Building your dialog:

```
Dialog dl = dialog.getDialog();
Button button = dl.findViewbyid(R.id.btn); //Replace with dialog button ID
button.setOnclicklistener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        clicked = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to use the ok button default to dialog fragment, no need defining one

Comment: cannot see any edit, I dont want to use this >>>> R.id.btn